# SoundCloud API track request by a specific ID giving me no response. All other tracks work

Tags: api, url, response, soundcloud

There is something really weird going on with the SoundCloud API regarding the /tracks endpoint.

I try to request a track by its ID. It works for all tracks except one single track ID giving me no response. There is no error, just a white page as response.
Only the track with the ID 274237707 is giving me no response.
Tracks with one higher or lower number does work.

The request is done by the following URL:
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/274237707?consumer_key=my-client-id

Is anyone else having the same issue with this track (ID = 274237707)?

Comment: Sorry the URL was corrupted: the consumer key is added at the end of the url: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/274237707?consumer_key=my-client-id

Comment: what documentation are you using? I see nothing about "consumer_key" in the API reference & I'm having some 404 - Not Found responses when trying to search for things.

Comment: consumer_key is the client id you get when you create an app on developers.soundcloud.com. its only called consumer key as get parameter in the url.

Comment: Is the ID even valid? What is the url of the track so we can verify.

Comment: It should not be consumer_key but client_id according to the track api (consumer_key also works but that is undocumented): https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks
But indeed this track gives the dreaded 403 Forbidden error. This means the track owner has disabled API access for this track.